# mysql - convert unix timestamps to datetime and how add other columns to the query?

Tags: mysql, datetime, converters, unix-timestamp, select-query

mysql - I have a table , a column of unix timestamps called `time`, which I have already changed to datetime format, but I can't select other columns of my table. 
To change the unix timestamps I have used the following statement:

```
SELECT
from_unixtime (time)
FROM 
  calllog
```

and changed to datetime format successfully, but when I add other columns to the select query the result is 1 in all the `time` columns. What can be done?

Comment: Show what other columns you are selecting. It seems unclear what you  are asking for.

Comment: Adding other columns shouldn't have any effect on this column. Show what you've written.

Comment: I have a table of 'bookings' of four columns named, country, city, ID  and also a 'time' columm which is in unix timestamps format. I want a mysql query that will give me a result of the table with the four columns but 'time' converted into human readable date. I found a select query just to convert the time column, but not to give me a result of the whole table with time converted ? ;S

Comment: I've tried SELECT id, country, city FROM flights WHERE from_unixtime (time)
FROM 
  flights and it lists all the table but the column unix_time with 1' . When I try by itself SELECt
from_unixtime (time)
FROM 
  calllog it converts the time successfully.